# Assets Unable to Load S3 Buckets; No Error Message

Tags: assets, s3

When loading the buckets for a new S3 source, Assets is failing silently (no buckets listed in select box, no error message), despite correct S3 credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enabling cURL in PHP resolved this issue.